# Pandas Pivot with Strings- ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

Given this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Field':['a','b','a','b'],'Value':['aa','bb','cc','dd'],
'indexer':[0,0,1,1]})

df
  Field Value  indexer
0     a    aa        0
1     b    bb        0
2     a    cc        1
3     b    dd        1
```

I want to produce a dataframe like this:

```
indexer   a   b
0         aa  bb
1         cc  dd
```

I've seen answers on how to achieve this when the value field is numeric, but I cannot seem to get this working with string data.

I've tried df.groupby('indexer') but cannot seem to display it or get it into a dataframe. I've found answers for these, but they assume float or integer values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem your real data contains duplicates in pairs `indexer` with `Field`, so is necessary some aggregate function like `', '.join`, because working with `string`s:

```
df = df.groupby(['indexer', 'Field'])['Value'].apply(', '.join).unstack()
print (df)
Field     a   b
indexer        
0        aa  bb
1        cc  dd
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='indexer', columns='Field', values='Value', aggfunc=','.join)
```

Comment: Thanks :-) , I did not notice that require join, when I saw your answer, thank you my friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas.crosstab).

Example:

```py
pd.crosstab(index=df.indexer, columns=df.field, aggfunc=lambda v:v)
```